# how to install shadowsocks-qt5 on CentOS7?

Tags: repository, shadowsocks

I have tried installation on [CentOS6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517284/how-to-install-shadowsocks-qt5-on-centos6), and got a lot of errors.

I am trying to install shadowsocks-qt5 on CentOS7.

I am doing this from China, so there are a lot of repo is not reachable.

I followed this [post](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5/wiki/Installation), add the repo file, and `sudo yum update` finished successfully.

`sudo yum install shadowsocks-qt5` end up with following:

```
Error downloading packages:
  zbar-0.10-27.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  GraphicsMagick-1.3.25-6.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  botan-1.10.14-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

any ideas?

Comment: I get the feeling you should update your original post instead of creating three separate but related posts. Have you made progress beyond your original two questions?